# App displays dark themes

Tags: android

This is **manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.simplebudget.mrtheqiu.simplebudget" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is **gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.simplebudget.mrtheqiu.simplebudget"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

What should I do?

I want it to be blue. The blue one that appears normally.

Comment: Provide your layout `xml`, or just check your background in your layout.

Comment: `@style/AppTheme`... What is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change theme from appcompat to hany holo theme in editor.[image]

Comment: I changed it than I changed the background manually .. it works .. thanks